# Why am I seeing these warnings in next js app?

Tags: next.js

I am creating a web app with nextjs and tailwind css.
When I am running or building the app I am getting these warnings -

```
remote: warning " &gt; react-live-clock@6.0.6" has unmet peer dependency "moment@^2.29.1".
remote: warning " &gt; react-moment@1.1.2" has unmet peer dependency "moment@^2.29.0".
remote: warning " &gt; react-moment@1.1.2" has unmet peer dependency "prop-types@^15.7.0".
remote: warning "eslint-config-next &gt; @typescript-eslint/parser &gt; @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree &gt; tsutils@3.21.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@&gt;=2.8.0 || &gt;= 3.2.0-dev || &gt;= 3.3.0-dev || &gt;= 3.4.0-dev || &gt;= 3.5.0-dev || &gt;= 3.6.0-dev || &gt;= 3.6.0-beta || &gt;= 3.7.0-dev || &gt;= 3.7.0-beta".
```

can someone explain how can I fix these? And will they cause any problems in production?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In teh warning it says what deps you are missing you simply need to npm install all the deps

```
npm install moment prop-types typescript
```

if that does not work you can

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm cache clean
npm install
```